# Can you change load balancer type on GCE?

Tags: load-balancing, kubernetes, google-compute-engine

I've created a L4 load balancer on GCE - where it should have been L7. Is there a way to change it to http/https load balancer anyhow?

Or create a new one, but transfer the IP address to the old one?

Comment: Creating a new ingress resource should do it.

Comment: @AnirudhRamanathan - but can I also transfer the assigned IP address to the new Ingress?

Comment: Transferring the IP address will not be possible. TCP Load Balancers in GCP use [regional IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/network/forwarding-rules) addresses while the L7 load balancer uses [Global IPs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/).